# What's the difference between these diode symbols?

Tags: symbol, standard

[image: Different ways to draw generic rectifier diodes.]

What's the difference between these three different ways of symbolising a generic rectifier diode: solid, outline and outline with connection between anode and cathode?

Comment: All 3 are in common use.

Comment: Amount of ink spent. Third one is more suited for hand drawing with templates since you can keep a straight line and then go back over it with a stencil later

Comment: the third one means "reverse protection diode I almost forgot when drawing this schematic" :)

Comment: @FrancoVS Interesting.

Comment: To me, the third symbol implies you've just dropped the diode on top of a wire, without breaking the wire, so there is a short circuit between the diode terminals.

Comment: You already have the correct answers, based on norms, but let me add this. I seem to remember that some textbook authors take the liberty to associate the filled and empty ones with different models of a diode. So, for example, one symbol can be used to represent an ideal diode with zero threshold and infinite V/I slope and another can represent a diode with fixed nonzero threshold and slope corresponding to rd, or the exponential model based on Shockley equation. Not a norm, not a shared use, just good all babel of self-imposed conventions. Just to teach, at the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filled symbol adheres to IEEE norms, the one with the line through it adheres to DIN/IEC norms, and the hollow one does not adhere to any norm.

Comment: Do you happen to have any links to more information about the DIN and IEC standards? I'd really like to educate myself about the differences between those and the IEEE standards.

Comment: http://pcad-libs.embedders.org/rules/ref_617.pdf Section 5.3 (page 79 / 05-6 in that document) Sorry, offical norms are paylinks.

Answer (score 4):

All of those are standard diodes you can get details in [image]

the original image is from the site below : 
https://www.tubefr.com/types-de-diodes.html

Answer (score 3):

IEEE Std 315, *Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams*, specifies this symbol for a "Semiconductor diode; semiconductor rectifier diode; metallic rectifier"

[image]

The letters in parentheses are not part of the symbol, and the enclosing circle is optional. So, at least in the U.S., the hollow symbols would be non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

They all indicate the same thing. Just a stylistic difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Micronta multimeter with schematic at the end of the owner's manual.  This shows most diodes solid black filled, but one diode not filled, white inside.  All were unlabeled, no parts list.  I did an internet search for other Micronta multimeters that did the same thing, finding several.  Eventually I was able to locate one that lists more about the diodes in the schematic.  **The white filled diodes were GERMANIUM diodes, and the black filled diodes were SILICON diodes.**  In general, I think the symbols are interchangeable and would not assume white filled diodes are always Ge type.  However, when the same document shows different symbols, it's worth investigating why.